# How to force Mac OS to open "Search with Google" in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, search, safari

While using Mac OS, its very useful to use "Search with Google" tool in context menu to directly search selected text from error windows or other content:

---

[image]

---

But problem is, that it always open Safari by default. I have Google Chrome as default browser, but it makes no sense.

Does anyone know how to force this option open in Google Chrome instead of Safari?

Comment: The solution on http://superuser.com/questions/369934 works pretty well.

Comment: This seems a bug / unwanted feature of OSX. What I would do is to provide feedback directly to Apple http://www.apple.com/feedback/ that way will be aware that some users are not happy with it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The OP is not using the context menu in Chrome, and does not have the "Search Google for...." option.

The "Search with Google" entry is provided by Safari and won't work with another browser to my knowledge.

The closest thing that I found in my journey to provide the same desire was to create a service of your own using Automator.

Instructions:

1. Open Automator and choose Service as the type
2. Add a "Run Shell Script" action by dragging it to the right pane
   [image]
3. Add script

   `open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"`

   Adjust the TLD as needed for your country specific Google page.
   ex: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=
4. Save the service as "Search Google"
5. Activate the service in System Preferences and optionally assign a keyboard shortcut. Once activated, "Search Google" will appear in the context menu 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to replace `.com` with my country specific `co.in` for Google address, otherwise it was opening only a blank google search page.

Comment: Thanks @YogeshUmeshVaity, good point. I've updated with a note for future visitors.

Comment: I use your service but want to duplicate it for a specific search purpose, mainly adding a few domains that should be excluded from the results, something like "-site:a.com -site:b.com". How do I concatenate in those parameters into the ruby expression in your example?

Comment: Excellent workaround. This is exactly I was looking for. Thank you!!!

Comment: instead of "Run shell script" you can also use "Run javascript", use script "function run(input, parameters) { return "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(input) }", and stack additional action "Internet > Open webpages" underneath. It could work faster.

Comment: "Services" are now called "Quick Actions" in Automator.  I'm not sure why, but this has trouble with pdfs in Preview.  I expect something needs to be done with the text format?

Comment: My problem is that while this adds an entry underneath the "services" menu, I still have the preconfigured "search with Google" that opens Safari at the top level. This is true even if the preconfigured one is unchecked in Preference. So,I still sometimes choose this by mistake (which appears to trigger a crash while sleeping). Any idea how to remove the unwanted preconfigured menu entry?

Comment: @Jice You can uncheck the entry in settings services searching catalog

Comment: @Youthoverturn if you are referring to the Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Services->Searching->"Search With Google", I do have that unchecked. However, still shows up in the Mail services menu. 
Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to choose "Search Google for..." near the *top* of the list in the right-click dialog box. If you choose "Search with Google" (near the bottom) it's still going to open Safari.

Comment: This is the wrong answer (see explanation below in answer from Casper)